# jQuery deferred done method not triggered when debugging

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox, firebug, jquery-deferred

I have a method which is making a jquery ajax call. That method returns the deferred object which is created by jquery when you use `$.ajax`:

```
function callWebservice() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {delay: 2}
    });
}
```

Right after calling that method I have a few 'done' handlers on different places in the code (which have access to the `Deferred` returned by that method):

```
$(function () {
    var dfr = callWebservice();
    dfr.done(function() { console.log('done 1');})
    dfr.done(function() { console.log('done 2');})
    dfr.done(function() { console.log('done 3');})
    dfr.done(function() { console.log('deferred state 2: ' + dfr.state());})
    console.log('deferred state 1: ' + dfr.state());
});
```

When I just run that code, all seems to be fine: I can see the 5 lines in the console, with the last one being: 'deferred state 2: resolved'.
When however I put a breakpoint on let's say the 2nd `done` **and wait for the webservice call to return**, then none of those 4 `done` handlers get called. In the console is 'deferred state 1: pending'.

Is this expected behavior? Is that deferred object not able to have it's state changed to 'resolved' because of debugging? Or am I not using it in a correct way?

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeLjB/3/) so you can easily simulate this behavior.

**[UPDATE]**
It seems to be indeed working in chrome. Also when debugging this in IE10 it works as expected.
When using Firefox's built in debugging tools it also works.. So it seems this is a bug in Firebug.

Comment: hmm... it seems to work for me, when i continue past the breakpoint it resolves and the done handlers get called.

Comment: Did you wait at least 2 seconds after continuing? The response of the webservice call is only arriving after a bit more then 2 seconds (hence I'm sending a delay:2 to the jsfiddle echo url).

Comment: Yes, waiting several seconds is fine.

Comment: So nothing is wrong with my code, yea? :)
I wasted hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong... It's probably a bug / feature of FF / firebug..

Comment: Yes, that's what i would suspect it to be, the code looks fine.

Comment: What should I do with this question? Delete it? Leave it as is? Write an answer describing the findings?

Comment: well, unless you know why it's happening, there really is no answer to it other than *"I don't know"*. you can either leave it open hoping someone else finds the answer, or you can close it. I personally would close it, but i'm biased, i don't use firebug to do my debugging.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39398/discussion-between-tweezz-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a [bug in Firebug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6205), or more precisely in the old Firefox debugger API it is using called JSD.
This bug will be fixed as soon as Firebug [switched to the new JSD2 API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421), which is [planned for the next major release](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Roadmap#Planned_Features_.2F_Changes).

Sebastian